# Can I use a single flat sheet of metal as an ultrasonic horn?

Tags: acoustics, cutting, ultrasound

I want to make an ultrasonic cutter for home use projects, something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-im2AgUe9w) or there are many online videos of industrial ultrasonic cutters in e.g. the food industry. A typical design of an ultrasonic cutter is below on the left (a). It has a booster (a shaped metal cylinder whose length has been tuned to match the resonance of the oscillator), and then a sonotrode (to do the same thing I believe). The sonotrode has a particular profile of its own.

What is the purpose of the wedge shape of the sonotrode profile and the slots?

If I replace both with a single flat sheet of metal (as in (b)), tuned to the resonance of the oscillator as will the professional version be - what will I lose in terms of performance from the professional version?[image]

Comment: Related [question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/44867/33437).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the various tapers and bulges along the length of the booster and sonotrode is to 1) extract the greatest amount of *energy* being fed into it by the oscillator, and then 2) to yield the greatest amount of oscillation *amplitude* right at the point of contact between the sonotrode and the workpiece.

A piece of sheet metal is too light and too flexible to permit either of these conditions from being met.